# Can we change text selection style in UITextfiled?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Is it possible to change a text selection style? I have attached screenshot here (https://i.stack.imgur.com/foqBxm.png). I need to set plain highlight like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/8R0s1.png. Any solution?

Update:
I resolved by adding following code,

```
 NSDictionary* d = [textField typingAttributes];
NSMutableDictionary* md = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:d];

md[NSBackgroundColorAttributeName] = [UIColor greenColor];
[textfield setTypingAttributes:md];
            textfield.text = @"test";
```

Thanks!

Comment: Try this [solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26456563/5133769). It should resolve your issue. Thanks!

Comment: Ok will check..

Comment: seet your textstyle as None

Comment: Sorry, cant understand. You mean textfield.borderstyle ? I beleive there is no property for text style.

Comment: Added solution! Please check question above.

Thanks!