# Subview button in textview disappearing when changing NSMutableAttributedString until scrolled to the top

Tags: ios, swift, scroll, uitextview, subview

I have been creating a highlighting system for my text view which is big enough to have scrolling enabled, at the bottom I have added a button using a subview which acts as a segue to the next view.

When I change the text with the function below the button disappears (not clickable or visible). **When I scroll to the top of the text view and then scroll down again, the button reappears**. Anyone knows why? Is there any way to refresh the display of the button?

Edit: The subview count does not change before or after the event.

```
func highlightText () {

    guard let text = self.textView.attributedText else {
        return
    }
    guard let range = self.textView.visibleBottomRange else {
        return
    }
    let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(attributedString:text)
    attributedString.addAttribute(NSBackgroundColorAttributeName, value: UIColor.yellow , range: range)

    self.textView.attributedText = attributedString
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer here:
[Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454037/uitextview-text-selection-and-highlight-jumping-in-ios-8)

using:
`self.textView.layoutManager.allowsNonContiguousLayout = false;`
allows the subview to stay visible while changing the attributed text of text view