# Is it possible to change selection color in UITextView iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, uitextview

**Default**

[image]

**Desired**

[image]

Changing tintColor on a UITextField changes the selection color, but I can't find any documentation for changing it in a UITextView.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you can change text selection color using `tintColor` property of `UITextView`.
Use this code to get the expected output.

```
self.textView.tintColor = .red
```

Also, You can do this from the storyboard, see the following image.

[image]
[image]

Comment: read the question he mean to change color of the selected text, what you are providing will change the color of whole text.

Comment: Hi, @HarjotSingh for your kind information 'tintColor' is not text color, tintColor change select text color, as the given requirement, Please check once and then put the comment here.

Comment: Hi Downvoter what's the wrong with this code, this code id given output as expected.

Comment: Hi Atul, no offense but check the other answer, your answer is incomplete.

Comment: Hi @HarjotSingh I have update answer see the attached image you can do this from storyboard also.

Comment: Perfect answer then.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26456563/8272698'

I found this answer above, unfortunately it is in objective c

But you can still see how they managed to do it.

```
- (void)highlight {

    NSRange selectedTextRange = self.textView.selectedRange;

    [attributedString addAttribute:NSBackgroundColorAttributeName
                             value:[UIColor redColor]
                             range:selectedTextRange];

    float sysVer = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] floatValue];
    if (sysVer < 8.0) {
        // iOS 7 fix
        self.textView.scrollEnabled = NO;
        self.textView.attributedText = attributedString;
        self.textView.scrollEnabled = YES;
    } else {
        self.textView.attributedText = attributedString;
    }
}
```

Basically they created a function called highlight. 
In the function they are looking for when a user actually highlights a selected portion. `self.textView.selectedRange` When they get the text range the user has selected. They give it an attribute and provide it colour.

Swift

```
let selectedText = textView.selectedRange
```

Create the attribute:

```
let myAttribute = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: selectedUIColor]
```

Provide it your attribute,

```
textView.textStorage.addAttributes(myAttribute, range: selectedText)
```

Use this in an action called by sender.

Hope this helps!